# How to Delete selected rows and Entire rows in a Unbounded DataGridView using a Delete Button in C# 2010?

Tags: .net

In My Project I'm Using a Unbounded DataGridView . In Which I made First Row as CheckBoxColumn With Header Check Box . I Provided My End User to select a single row or multiple row or Entire rows in DataGridView and can delete it if they need it . But the real Problem is When I Select all rows and click delete it deletes Entire rows and while i select a single row it performs the same action.

Below is my delete Button code .

```
private void BtnDcDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    do
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewEx1.Rows)
        {
            try
            {
                dataGridViewEx1.Rows.Remove(row);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
    } while (dataGridViewEx1.Rows.Count > 1);
}
```

Comment: Never swallow exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewEx1.Rows)
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewEx1.SelectedRows) { 
...
```